# Grouping items upto two levels based on values using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

I have the following scenario:

I get JSON data of the item information. I parse it and use it in the HTML.
The data is of the following format :

```
{"classification": "books","category": "comics","Code": "ITBCBAT08","Title": ...}, ...
```

However, now I need to put them under sections as per respective classification AND category combination.

While parsing through results , I tried getting a unique set of Classifications in an array, and category in another array :

```
if ( $.inArray(this.classification, rO.classification) == -1 )
     rO.classification.push(this.classification);

if ( $.inArray(this.category, rO.category) == -1 )
     rO.category.push(this.category);
```

With the above I checked while printing HTML, however could not for the combination.

Here is an example fiddle of the above : http://jsfiddle.net/ZGp2z/2/

The output to be like

```
<div class="ClassificationName">

    <h2>Classification Name</h2>

    <div class="categoryName">
       <h3>Category Name</h3>
           <!-- Items that have the above Classification and Category -->
    </div>

    <div class="categoryName2">
       <h3>Category Name2</h3>
           <!-- Items that have the above Classification and Category2 -->
    </div>

</div>
...
```

Could someone please help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 possible ways of solving this:

1: Pass the data once and organize it in multidimensional object and the loop over it to output the result.

2: For each item, create and append to the DOM the classification and category if they aren't already, and then append the item name at the specific position. But this would be a ton of DOM manipulation and probably less efficient.

Here is a possible solution with reformatting data first (1).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZGp2z/17/

```
sO = [
        {
            "classification": "books",
            "category": "comics",
            "Code": "ITBCBAT08",
            "Title": "Dark Knight"
        },
        {
            "classification": "cds",
            "category": "comics",
            "Code": "ITCCCSUP02",
            "Title": "Superman"
        },
        {
            "classification": "books",
            "category": "literature",
            "Code": "ITBLII01",
            "Title": "To Kill a Mockingbird"
        }
    ];

     // Result = $.parseJSON(sO);
     Result = sO;

var html = "", data = {}, cls, cat;

for(var i in sO) {
    cls = sO[i].classification;
    cat = sO[i].category;

    if(typeof data[cls] === "undefined") {
        data[cls] = [];
    }

    if(typeof data[cls][cat] === "undefined") {
        data[cls][cat] = [];
    }

    data[cls][cat].push(sO[i]);
}

for(var cls in data) {
    html += "<div class=\"main\" style='display:block' >";
    html += "<h2>" + cls  + "</h2>";

    for(var cat in data[cls]) {
        html += "<h3>" + cat  + "</h3>"

        for(var item in data[cls][cat]) {
            html += "<p>" + data[cls][cat][item].Title + "</p>";   
        }
    }

    html += "</div>";
    html += "<div class=\"clr\"></div>";
}
$('#test').append(html);
```

Points of improvement:

1. use hasOwnProperty in the for-in loops

Answer (score 0):

Shall give you a algo!

1. First you have to sort the object list
2. Have a variable called PreviousClassification.
3. Iterate through the objects

4.If `previousClassification` is empty or equal to the `currentClassification`. then just append the category name and then asssign the `currentClassification` to `previousClassification`

1. If not, close the `classification` Div and open a new `Classification` Div for the new `Classification`
2. if the  index value equals to length-1 , the close the `classificationDiv`